# Not able to call solidity contract function (public payable function) from React

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethers.js, react

I am using truffle framework to deploy my solidity smart contract on local Ganache GUI.

Everything is on my local. I have configured the truffle config to use local ganache blockchain.

On the front-end app I am using `ReactJS` with `ethers.js`. I am also using Metamask (chrome extension) in which I have setup the local ganache RPC correctly (I believe).

**THIS IS WORKING CORRECTLY -**
I have public `testfxn` on my solidity contract deployed on local ganache. This `testfxn` function just returns a uint value `123`.
Now from the front-end react app, I click a button - it opens metamask ---- this react  app then  correctly invokes the `testfxn` and I am correctly able to console log `123` (the smart contract's returned value)
Working code (React using ethers.js) -

```
      const accounts = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
      console.log(accounts);  // logs correctly the account
      const signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);

      const balance = await provider.getBalance(accounts[0]);

      const balanceInEther = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);

      const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(
                      "0x9bd3fdf893 ..... f36597E5e224f95", 
                      contractABI, 
                      signer)

      const testcall = await contractInstance.testfxn();
      console.log(testcall);    // CORRECTLY logs 123
```

Definition of testfxn (on solidity contract deployed on ganache):-

```
    function testfxn() public pure returns( uint ){
        return 123;
    }
```

**BELOW CODE IS NOT WORKING-**
Instead of calling `textfxn` if I call `troublefxn` ..... I get the error.
Non-working code (in react)  -

```
      const accounts = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
      console.log(accounts);  // logs correctly the account
      const signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);

      const balance = await provider.getBalance(accounts[0]);

      const balanceInEther = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);

      const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(
                      "0x9bd3fdf893 ..... f36597E5e224f95", 
                      contractABI, 
                      signer)

        await contractInstance.troublefxn(5,
                                            {value: ethers.utils.parseEther("8.0")}
                                            );

       // Get error exception -
```

Error exception -

```
    "code": -32603,
    "message": "Internal JSON-RPC error.",
    "data": {
        "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
        "code": -32000,
        ...
```

`troublefxn` definition on solidity contract -

```
    function troublefxn(  uint f1, 
        ) public payable {

        some_state_variable = f1;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong in calling `troublefxn` from my react app ?

Comment: I have good amount of test ethers in my metamask wallet

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call wait() on the transaction.

Make the transaction a variable

`const tx = await contractInstance.troublefxn({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("8.0")});`

and then call `await tx.wait()`

which will wait for the transaction to be mined.